# Specification of relative resource paths in ASP.NET projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am in the process of getting an ASP.NET website project under version control, but am having some difficulty adapting my code from a one computer setup to a multiple-editor setup.

Currently, there are strings in this project that load resources by specifying an absolute path (e.g. "C:\Users...\file.ext") Obviously, the working copies of the project will not be the same for each user's computer, and so this path needs to change. Is there any way to specify the location of that resource relative to the root of the project? I tried using ~, but that does not seem to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried mapping the relative path to a physical path:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    string fooBarLocation = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/foo.bar");
    // at this stage fooBarLocation will probably resemble something like this:
    // c:\users\foo\bar\mysite\App_Data\foo.bar

    // TODO: do something with this foo.bar file 
    // like for example reading its contents
}
```

Comment: @smb510, if this post helped you solve the problem you were having please [mark it as answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the tick next to it.